# Is there a way of selecting multiple values based on user selection in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

hello guys please I am trying to select multiple data from the database with JSP and MySQL based on user selection in a drop-down in the picture below when the user selects the value from the dropdown that value will be added to the select condition and if it's not selected it will be eliminated this is my query but it's not working this is my query

```
sql="select * from copform where marital='"+marital+"' or mtype='"+memT+"' or empStatus='"+empS+"' or edul='"+edul+"' or occu='"+occu+"' or wbap='"+bab+"' or hbap='"+bab+"' and assembly='"+assembly+"' and gender='Female'";
```

and the dropdown form is in the picture below
[user selection dropdown form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftkgq.png)

so in case the user selects 3 values then how do I fetch data for only those 3 values

Comment: You have to create a dynamic query for this. Also, your query is not good as it will allow SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized query. OR you can set DB  NULL in those parameters where the user has selected nothing and use COALESCE IN your query.

Comment: Try using `CriteriaBuilder` for dynamically building queries. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing **marital** as a string(VARCAHR) value, you don't have to again give it inside a single quotation mark. That might be the issue.

```
sql="select * from copform where marital="+marital+"
```

use above instead,

```
sql="select * from copform where marital='"+marital+"'
```